# Unsafe certificate protection in Android?

Tags: security

Maybe I'm wrong. If so, please let me know.

Here is my question. I've followed the instructions [here](http://support.google.com/ics/nexus/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1649774) and installed my personal certificate stored in a pfx file (PKCS#12) in my Google Nexus (ICS 4.0.4). A little problem here is that it is not listed in "User" tab in "Credentials". It works anyway.

But the big problem IMHO, is the way Android protects your certificates by default. It only requests the user to set a pattern, PIN, or password to unlock the screen. I'm missing a password-protected access to my credentials like IE does in Windows for instance every time your certificate is requested by a site.

Is there a method to enhance security of your certificates in ICS?

Thank you

Comment: Did you mean Nexus S? Or Nexus One?

Comment: @AleksandarStefanović, it was Nexus S

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps any, but have you seen [CACertMan](https://f-droid.org/wiki/page/info.guardianproject.cacert) (also [on GitHub](https://github.com/guardianproject/cacert)) yet?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the link dies. For further hints, please see: [How do I write a good answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Besides, the linked F-Droid page explicitly mentions: *The app won't work with Android 4+ anyway* – so it won't help the OP (he's on 4.0.4).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, CACertMan (as far as I can see) only allows you to disable pre-installed certs which is not what the OP is asking for.